# What's the drawback of `let count = useRef(0).current`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

## Example Code:

(Pretend we are inside component function)

```js
let count = useRef(0).current

useEffect(()=>{
  count++
  console.log(count)
}, [count])
```

## Question:

1. What will happen if I run this code

(I am afraid that the endless loop execution will blow up my m1 chip macbookair, so I didn't run ^_^).

2. Should I awalys `some_ref_object.curent = some_value` to change the value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code probably will not do what you expect.

`useRef` returns a mutable object, where the object is shared across renders. But if you extract a *property* from that object into a variable and then reassign that variable, the object won't change.

For the same reason, reassigning the number below doesn't change the object:

```js
const obj = { foo: 3 };

let { foo } = obj;
foo = 10;

console.log(obj);
```

In your code, the ref object never gets mutated. It is *always* the following object:

```
{ current: 0 }
```

So

```
let count = useRef(0).current
```

results in `count` being initially assigned to 0 at the beginning of every render.

This might be useful if for some odd reason you wanted to keep track of a number inside a given render, not to persist for any other render - but in such a case, it'd make a lot more sense to remove the ref entirely and just do

```
let count = 0;
```

Your effect hook won't do anything useful either - since `count` is always 0 at the start of every render, the effect callback will never run (except on the first render).

> Should I awalys some_ref_object.curent = some_value to change the value

You should use `current`, not `curent`. But yes - if you want the change to persist, assign to a property of the object, instead of reassigning a standalone variable. (Reassigning a standalone variable will almost never have any side-effects.)

But, if you have something in the view that the count is used in - for example, if you want to return it in the JSX somewhere - you probably want **state** instead of a ref (or a `let count = 0;`), so that setting state results in the component re-rendering and the view updating.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it on my colleague's computer, and fortunately it didn't blow up

### Conclusion 1:

The useEffect won't effect, because ref can't be denpendency.

### Conclusion 2:

Only `let count = useRef(0).current` is the right way.

Comment: Why would it blow up? :D

Comment: @SinanYaman Because I'm afraid calling an infinite loop :P